# Saving partial spark DStream window to HDFS

Tags: hdfs, apache-spark, apache-storm, hadoop-streaming, spark-streaming

I am counting values in each window and find the top values and want to save only the top 10 frequent values of each window to hdfs rather than all the values.

```
eegStreams(a) = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, group, Map(args(a) -> 1),StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER).map(_._2)
    val counts = eegStreams(a).map(x => (math.round(x.toDouble), 1)).reduceByKeyAndWindow(_ + _, _ - _, Seconds(4), Seconds(4))
    val sortedCounts = counts.map(_.swap).transform(rdd => rdd.sortByKey(false)).map(_.swap)
    ssc.sparkContext.parallelize(rdd.take(10)).saveAsTextFile("hdfs://ec2-23-21-113-136.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9000/user/hduser/output/" + (a+1))}      


    //sortedCounts.foreachRDD(rdd =>println("\nTop 10 amplitudes:\n" + rdd.take(10).mkString("\n")))
    sortedCounts.map(tuple => "%s,%s".format(tuple._1, tuple._2)).saveAsTextFiles("hdfs://ec2-23-21-113-136.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9000/user/hduser/output/" + (a+1))
```

I can print top 10 as above (commented).

I have also tried

```
sortedCounts.foreachRDD{ rdd => ssc.sparkContext.parallelize(rdd.take(10)).saveAsTextFile("hdfs://ec2-23-21-113-136.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9000/user/hduser/output/" + (a+1))}
```

but I get the following error. My Array is not serializable

> 15/01/05 17:12:23 ERROR actor.OneForOneStrategy:
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext
>   java.io.NotSerializableException:
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
sortedCounts.foreachRDD(rdd => rdd.filterWith(ind => ind)((v, ind) => ind <= 10).saveAsTextFile(...))
```

Note: I didn't test the snippet...

Answer (score 0):

Your first version should work. Just declare `@transient ssc = ...` where the Streaming Context is first created.

The second version won't work b/c `StreamingContext` cannot be serialized in a closure.